# Bootstrap 3 grids: column under column inside one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I have following HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel 1 (left)
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="col-lg-6">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel 2 (center)
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel 3 (right)
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel 2-2 (under panel 2)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Final result should look like this:
[image]
And it works, but if panel 3 have bigger height than panel 1 or 2 I get this:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have to put Panel-2-2 under Panel 2, why is it in the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you should have done it, by nesting the Panel 2-2 under Panel 2 instead of letting it lie at the end, which is not what you'll want. Here's the Bootply:http://bootply.com/102721

**Code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel 1 (left)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel 2 (center)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">Panel 2-2 (under panel 2)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>Panel 3 (right)
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**

[image]